# UIImage stretchableImage

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know if Apple provides the stretchableImage's used to create the delete buttons as a resource or if anyone knows where I can obtain these. I know I could create them myself but I don't want to have to do the work that's already been done.

Comment: exactly what delete buttons? in UITableViewCells?

Comment: For example the "Delete Contact" button at the bottom of the edit contact view in the phone app.